# Get columns values in data table using linq from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datatable

I am new to LINQ queries, please help me out to find the solution.

I have a source in Entity Framework data model, there is a table `currency` bound to the source with columns `currencyID` and `CurrencyName`.

I need to get the values from the database to the `DataTable` using a LINQ query.

I tried something like mentioned below but it's not working:

```
 var dataset = Source.T_Currency
    .Where(x=> x.CurrencyID == x.CurrencyID &&  x.CurrencySymbol == x.CurrencySymbol)
    .Select(x => new x.Currency
    {
        CurrencyID = x.CurrencyID,
        CurrencySymbol = x.CurrencySymbol
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all rows from T_Currency then try

```
Source.T_Currency
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.CurrencyID,
        x.CurrencySymbol
    })
    .ToList()
```

To filter result by any value add Where statement before Select:

```
Source.T_Currency
    .Where(x => x.CurrencySymbol == myCurrency) // where myCurrency is variable/parameter
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.CurrencyID,
        x.CurrencySymbol
    })
    .ToList()
```

It is example with Select statement but actually in this case it is not requied, so Source.T_Currency.ToLost() returns the same result as the first code snippet. Difference is in type of values but if you can use original class then you should not create anonimous type.

Comment: Yes I want to select all the rows from T_Currency into a data table.

Comment: ` DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(t))
                {
                    table.Load(reader);
                }`

Answer (score 0):

you should use LINQ Join like this example:

```
        var custSupJoin =
            from sup in suppliers
            join cust in customers on sup.Country equals cust.Country
            select new { Country = sup.Country, SupplierName = sup.SupplierName, CustomerName = cust.CompanyName };
```